# Error handling when uploading file using multer with expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, multer, busboy

I am using [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) to save the file on server developed through express & nodejs.

I am usign following code.

```
var express = require('express'),
    multer  = require('multer')

var app = express()

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.post('/upload',[ multer({ dest: './uploads/'}), function(req, res){

    res.status(204).end()
}]);

app.listen(3000);
```

Multer saves the file for me in the specified destination folder.

**All this is working fine but I have following questions:**

1. If the file saving fails for various reasons, it looks like my route will always return status 204.
2. I am not sure if status 204 is retured after file is saved or while the file is getting saved asynchronously, status 204 is returned.

Comment: For **2022** it's important to note that **if there's an error multer simply passes along to your normal Express error route**.  If for some reason you need to handle it separately, see Arya's code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can handle errors using the [`onError`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#onerror) option:

```
app.post('/upload',[
  multer({
    dest    : './uploads/',
    onError : function(err, next) {
      console.log('error', err);
      next(err);
    }
  }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.status(204).end();
  }
]);
```

If you call `next(err)`, your route handler (generating the 204) will be skipped and the error will be handled by Express.

<s>I *think* (not 100% sure as it depends on how `multer` is implemented) that your route handler will be called when the file is saved. You can use [`onFileUploadComplete`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#onfileuploadcomplete-file-req-res) to log a message when the upload is done, and compare that to when your route handler is called.</s>

Looking at the code, `multer` calls the next middleware/route handler when the file has been uploaded completely.

Comment: `onError` was removed in Multer 1.0.0.

Comment: I've found an working code with new multer version: https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/336#issuecomment-242906859

Comment: what is the replacement of onError ?

Comment: @HosMercury https://github.com/expressjs/multer#error-handling

Comment: How to handle if multer upload is successful and route handler fails?

Comment: @m9m9m that would depend on how the route handler is implemented, and what exactly you mean by handling it.

Answer (score 30):

This is how to write multer middleware that handle upload and errors

```
const multer = require("multer");

function uploadFile(req, res, next) {
    const upload = multer().single('yourFileNameHere');

    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
            // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
        } else if (err) {
            // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
        }
        // Everything went fine. 
        next()
    })
}
```

Comment: Note that if you write a response then you should *not* call `next()`, if I understand correctly.

Comment: accepted answer doesn't works anymore, this one should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
var upload = multer().single('avatar')

app.post('/profile', function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      // An error occurred when uploading 
      return
    }

    // Everything went fine 
  })
}
```

ref :

http://wiki.workassis.com/nodejs-express-get-post-multipart-request-handling-example/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#error-handling

Answer (score 2):

According to the ***multer*** documentation (https://github.com/expressjs/multer#error-handling)

> **Error handling**

> When encountering an error, Multer will delegate the error to Express. You can display a nice error page using the standard express way.

> If you want to catch errors specifically from Multer, ***you can call the middleware function by yourself.*** Also, if you want to catch only the Multer errors, you can use the MulterError class that is attached to the multer object itself (e.g. err instanceof multer.MulterError).

> **code sample**
>
> ```
>    const multer = require('multer')
>    const upload = multer().single('avatar')
>    
>    app.post('/profile', function (req, res) {
>      upload(req, res, function (err) {
>        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
>          // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
>        } else if (err) {
>          // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
>        }
>    
>        // Everything went fine.
>      })
>    })
> ```

When we re-write the code in this question with latest version of multer (v1.4.5-lts.1)

```
const express = require('express');

const multer = require('multer');

const app = express();

const upload = multer({ dest: './uploads/' }).single('fieldName');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello world');
});

app.post(
    '/upload',
    (req, res, next) => {
        upload(req, res, (err) => {
            if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
                res.status(404).send(err + 'Upload failed due to multer error');
            } else if (err) {
                res.status(404).send(err + 'Upload failed due to unknown error');
            }
            // Everything went fine.
            next();
        });
    },
    (req, res) => {
        res.status(204).end();
    }
);

app.listen(3000);
```

To check the Multer errors and non multer errors we can add validations using fileFilter and limits
eg:
I am adding a CSV file filter method and some limits

```
// CSV file filter - will only accept files with .csv extension
const csvFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log('csv filter working');
    if (file.mimetype.includes('csv')) {
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb('Please upload only csv file.', false);
    }
};

// adding the csv file checking, file number limit to 1 and file size limit 10 1kb
const upload = multer({
    dest: './uploads/',
    fileFilter: csvFilter,
    limits: { files: 1, fileSize: 1024 } 
}).single('fieldName');
```

We can see different errors are thrown when we try to upload non CSV file or >1kb sized file or multiple files.

Answer (score 2):

Since Multer is designed for express to use as middleware, by default call `next(err)` which falls into nearest error handler middleware

```
var express = require('express'),
  multer = require('multer')

var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.post('/upload', multer({ dest: './uploads/' }),

  function (req, res, next) {
    // your logic goes here

    res.status(204).end()
  },
  function (err, req, res, next) {
    // handle your error here
    // if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
    //   // handle file size error
    //   if (err.code === 'LIMIT_FILE_SIZE') return res.status(400).send({ error: err.message });
    //   // handle unexpected file error
    //   if (err.code === 'LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE') return res.status(400).send({ error: err.message });
    //   // handle unexpected field key error
    //   if (err.code === 'LIMIT_FIELD_KEY') return res.status(400).send({ error: err.message });
    // }

    res.status(400).end()
  },);

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the code below (the source from the muter index.js file), if you not pass the **onError** callback the error will be handled by express.

```
    fileStream.on('error', function(error) {
      // trigger "file error" event
      if (options.onError) { options.onError(error, next); }
      else next(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the system when the user sends anything to you

I usually set more [*option1]:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(ls){
  // console.log(ls);
  (function(){})();
});
```

And then:

```
var upload= multer({ dest: __dirname + '/../uploads/' }).single('photos');
// middle ..
upload(req, res, function (err) {
  if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
    // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
    console.log('MulterError', err);
  } else if (err) {
    // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
    // Work best when have [*option1]
    console.log('UnhandledError', err);
  }
  if(err) {
    return res.sendStatus(403);
  }
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

package: "multer": "^1.4.2"

Answer (score 1):

```
    var multer = require('multer')
    var upload = multer().single('avatar')
     
    app.post('/profile', function (req, res) {
      upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
          handle error
        } else if (err) {
          handle error
        }
        else{
          write you code
        }
      })
    })
```

you can see this from the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#error-handling)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is handling error with middleware.

```
const multerErrorHandling = (err, req, res, next) => {
if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
  res.status(400).send("Multer error: " + err.message);
} else {
  next();
}
};
  // you should use after multer to send another respond.
  app.post("/upload", singleUpload,multerErrorHandling,(req, res) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but it might help others.

> Here is how I handle errors and use it safely in my express/typescript
> project.

```
const upload = (fieldName: string) => {
  return (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    return multer({
      storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, cb) => {
          if (file.fieldname === 'post') {
            return cb(null, `${path.join(path.dirname(__dirname), 'uploads/postImg')}`);
          } else if (file.fieldname === 'profile') {
            return cb(null, `${path.join(path.dirname(__dirname), 'uploads/ProfilePic')}`);
          } else {
            return cb(new Error(`${file.fieldname} is incorrect`), null);
          }
        },
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
          return cb(null, `${file.originalname}-${Date.now()}-${file.fieldname}`);
        },
      }),
      fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        const fileExtension = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
        if (!(fileExtension in allowedFiles)) return cb(null, false);
        return cb(null, true);
      },
      dest: `${path.join(path.dirname(__dirname), 'uploads')}`,
      limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 3, // 3MB
        files: 1,
      },
    }).single(fieldName)(req, res, (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        // handle file size error
        if (err.code === 'LIMIT_FILE_SIZE') return res.status(400).send({ error: err.message });
        // handle unexpected file error
        if (err.code === 'LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE') return res.status(400).send({ error: err.message });
        // handle unexpected field key error
        if (err.code === 'LIMIT_FIELD_KEY') return res.status(400).send({ error: err.message });
      }
      next();
    });
  };
};




app.post("/upload", (req: Request, res:Response)=>{
res.json({message:"file uploaded"})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To bring in notice, that *middleware is called when the exact route is hit*.
Keeping this in mind, we don't want the multer to be called directly, rather we want to create another middleware that should call multer instead.

Firstly, when **uploadMiddleware** is being called, the **upload.single()** function gets invoked and returns another function with parameters req, res
and a callback function. The callback function has a parameter error (if error is occurred), so, if the error has a value a undefined, congratulations, no error has occurred. And the **next()** function of uploadMiddleware is called and further code is executed.

Follow code and its explanation Above:

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req , file , cb){
        cb(null , 'uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req , file ,cb){
        cb(null,`${Date.now()}${file.originalname}`)
    },
})
const upload = multer({ storage })

function uploadMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    try {
        upload.single('photos')(req, res, function(err) {
            if(err) res.status(400).json({status: 'error', message: err.message})
            else next()
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('errorrororororororoor');
    }
}

app.post('/file', uploadMiddleware, (req, res) => {
    res.end();
})
```