# Multer limit images accepted

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, multer

I am working with Multer and Multer S3 to allow users to upload images on a Node project. I am wanting the user to be able to upload 3 images regardless of their size but no more. If a user tries to select say 6 images I get this error page:

```
Error: Unexpected field
   at makeError
```

How would I change my code below to not allow a user to select/upload more than 3 images and/or handle the error in a better way.

***Partial Code:***

```
router.post("/", upload.array('image', 3), function(req, res, next){

          var filepath = undefined;

          var filepath2 = undefined;

          var filepath3 = undefined;

        if(req.files[0]) {
            filepath = req.files[0].key;
        } 

          if(req.files[1]) {
            filepath2 = req.files[1].key;
        } 

         if(req.files[2]) {
            filepath3 = req.files[2].key;
        }.....
```

Update:

I added this and now I land on a "too many files" error page if the user tries to upload more than 3. Now I just have to figure out how to redirect if too many files.

```
  var upload = multer({
    limits : { files: 3 },
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/expressjs/multer#limits , is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks @SamipSuwal! Yeah I tried to implement the max number of file fields aspect but kept getting the same error. Hmm

Comment: so if a user tries to update 3 or less files then your code works?

Comment: @SamipSuwal That's correct. I just want to limit it to 3 max.

Comment: @SamipSuwal - Check out the update above

Comment: take a look at this to catch errors specifically from multer https://github.com/expressjs/multer#error-handling and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30838901/error-handling-when-uploading-file-using-multer-with-expressjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with multer and here is something that I was able to get working.

Define your multer setup like this

```
var upload = multer().array('image', 3);
```

Then modify your function to this,

```
router.post("/", function(req, res, next){
   upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
           //redirect your user here ...
           return;
        }

        //no multer error proceed with your normal operation ...

   })
});
```