# Is it possible to use multer inside router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

Is it possible to use multer inside router like example below?

```
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
   multer({});
}
```

Comment: Please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30838901/error-handling-when-uploading-file-using-multer-with-expressjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible with multer.

They have used this in one of their example in Error Handling section.
[Multer Error Handling](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#error-handling)

```
var multer = require('multer')
var upload = multer().single('avatar')

app.post('/profile', function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
    } else if (err) {
      // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
    }

    // Everything went fine.
  })
})
```